# Returning a list from a Dapper stored procedure

Tags: c#, dapper

I have a dapper method, that I want to store against a class.

```
        using (var block = new TransactionBlock())
        {
            const string sql =
                "select * from Messages where statusId not in ('5','6')";
            var results = TransactionBlock.Connection.Query<OpenMessages>
            (sql,TransactionBlock.Transaction).ToList();
            block.Commit();
            return results;
        }
```

So, OpenMessages is :

```
   public class OpenMessages
   {
      public List<string> MessageId { get; set; }
   }
```

The following error is being returned:

System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=ExecuteReader requires the command to have a transaction when the connection assigned to 
  the command is in a pending local transaction.  The Transaction property of the command has not 
  been initialized.

I have several other methods, that are working fine, just not this one that I need to return a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing the transaction in as the parameters. Name it:

```
var results = TransactionBlock.Connection.Query<OpenMessages>
        (sql,
   transaction: TransactionBlock.Transaction).ToList();
```

Also, if it really is a stored procedure you probably want to add:

```
commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure
```

Comment: Hi Marc, yes your right, the complete version is a SP, the inline SQL string was to try and illustrate what was happening.